# rbenv or bundler gemset sandboxing?

Tags: ruby, bundler, rbenv

The rbenv documentation states that you can use the gemsets plugin to sandbox your gems if you aren't using bundler:

```
Manage gemsets. Bundler is a better way to manage application dependencies. If you have projects that are not yet using  Bundler you can install the rbenv-gemset plugin.
```

However, I am using bundler and when I switch between projects that have different gemsets I need to re-bundle. When I was using rvm, this was simple due to the .gemsets file.

Is there a sandboxing functionality in bundler that I am not aware of or have I misunderstood the documentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

bundler uses the `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` files in, in essense, to make a "gemset" for that particular project that you access via commands prefixed with `bundle exec`

Comment: But if I change between projects that are both using the bundler gemfiles, i will have a whole bunch of gems not relevant to my current project. So the bundler gemset isn't equivalent to a gemset sandbox

Comment: But you also wont have duplicated gems installed in multiple gemsets on the same machine for no reason.  What is the harm with it?  Using bundler & bundle exec wont let you access those "other" gems anyways

Comment: @Coderama Even with sandboxes, every time you need to upgrade gems in your Gemfile, you'll have unused old gems lying around. I suppose someone could write a cleanup script to clean up the current sandbox using the current Gemfile.lock... but why bother?

Comment: I agree with Coderama. I don't want to install new gems in the environment of an old app. RVM's gemset functionality is very useful.

Answer (score 5):

I found this clear, well-documented solution:

[Setting up and installing rbenv, ruby-build, rubies, rbenv-gemset, and bundler](https://gist.github.com/2407918)

> Now when you gem install (see “Bundler” section below) something it will go to your helloset gem area.
>
> You can combine use of multiple gemsets with it.
>
> The big benefit to this setup is enabling each project to use a different set of differently versioned gems.

Read the section entitled `Enable RVM-style “gemsets” (optional)`.

It uses the rbenv plugin for gemsets: https://github.com/jamis/rbenv-gemset.

Update 8/12/2012 
I am using this to manage two projects with different versions of Ruby, and separate sets of gems. It works well.

Answer (score 1):

It may have to do with the way rbevn uses shims. You might want check out 
https://github.com/carsomyr/rbenv-bundler

Answer (score 1):

Try using [chgems](https://github.com/postmodern/chgems#readme) with Bundler. chgems is like [chroot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot) for RubyGems. It spawns a new sub-shell with `PATH`, `GEM_HOME` and `GEM_PATH` updated to use `$project/.gem/$ruby/$version` as the primary `GEM_HOME`. Since all gems are installed inside of the project directory, cleaning up after a project is as easy as `rm -rf $project/`.